# Convergence in $L^p$ imply convergence in the space of tempered distributions?

Tags: functional-analysis

A query, does convergence in $L^p$ imply convergence in the space of tempered distributions?

If $f_k\to g$ in $L^p$ then $f_k\to g$ in $\mathcal{S}'$? with $\mathcal{S}'$ tempered distributions.

Note: $f_k$ and $g$ are identified with $T_{f_k}$ and $T_g $ where $T_f(\varphi)=\int f(x)\varphi(x)dx$ for any $\varphi\in\mathcal{S}.$

Comment: should it be $f_n\to g$ in $L^p$?

Comment: oh yes my mistake

Comment: This is an immedaite cosnequence of Holder's inequality. Just remember that $\phi$ belongs to every $L^{q}$.

Comment: yes now i understandt it
$f_k\to f$ in $L^p$ equivalent to $g_k\to 0$ in $L^p$ (with $g_k=f_k-f$) then $|g_k\psi|_1\leq |g_k|_p |\psi|_{p'}\to 0$ for any $\psi\in\mathcal{S}$ and $p'$ conjugate of $p.$

Therefore $|g_k\psi|_1\to 0$ i.e.$ \int g_k(x)\psi(x)dx\to 0$ or $T_{g_k}\to 0$ in $\mathcal{S}'$

Comment: @eraldcoil you should write this up as an answer and accept it!

Comment: @eraldcoil   $(f_k-g)1_{|f_k-g|>1} \to 0$ in $L^1$ and $(f_k-g)1_{|f_k-g|\le 1} \to 0$ in $L^1_{loc}$, this implies that $\int (f_k-g) \varphi\to 0$ for $\varphi\in L^\infty\cap L^1$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the topology in $\mathcal{S}$ is generated by the pseudonorms
\begin{align}
\rho_m(\phi):=\sup_{\substack{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\\|\beta|\leq m}} |(1+|x|^2)^m\partial^\beta\phi(x)|,\qquad m\in\mathbb{Z}_+
\end{align}
$\phi\in\mathcal{S}$.

Let $\phi\in\mathcal{S}$ and $1\leq p<\infty$.
Since
\begin{align}
|\phi(x)|=(1+|x|^2)^n|\phi(x)|\frac{1}{(1+|x|^2)^n}
\leq \frac{\rho_n(\phi)}{(1+|x|^2)^n},
\end{align}
we have that
\begin{align*}
    \|\phi\|_p&\leq \Big(\int^\infty_0\frac{1}{(1+|x|^2)^{np}}\,dx\Big)^{1/p}\rho_n(\phi)
  \end{align*}
Thus, if $f\in\mathcal{L}_q(\mathbb{R})$,  $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, and $u_f(\phi)=\int f\phi$, then
$$|u_f(\phi)|\leq \|f\|_q\|\phi\|_p\leq C_{n, p}\|f\|_q\rho_n(\phi)$$
this means that $u_f\in \mathcal{S}^*$. Also, from this inequalities the desired conclusion in the OP follows:
$$|(u_{f_k}-u_f)(\phi)|\leq C_{n, p}\|f_k-f\|_q\rho_n(\phi)\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty}0$$
for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.